# Is there a way to prevent a number from being negative in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, negative-number

Is there any other more convenient way of preventing variable from going negative than a `if` statement?

#### Example code

```
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset,
    sW = (44 - .06*scrollTop);

if( sW < 0 ){ sW = 0; }
```

Comment: `sW = sW < 0 ? 0 : sW;`

Comment: Is `sw = Math.max((44 - .06*scrollTop), 0)` more convenient?

Comment: `sw = Math.max(sw, 0)`

Comment: what is inconvenient with your way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). It will return the largest of its arguments.

```
sW = Math.max(0, sW);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use this...

```
var sW = (44 - .06*scrollTop);
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset, ( sW > 0 ? sW : 0 );
```

Im too slow ;)